# Is there are way to start with a specific value in foreach loop of PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Let say I have an array as follows:

```
$my_array = array(
    "fruit1" => "apple",
    "fruit2" => "orange",
    "notfruit" => "hamburger",
    "fruit3" => "banana"
)
```

Is there a way I can choose to start with $my_array['notfruit'] in an foreach loop of PHP? I don't care the sequence except the first one.

Currently I can think of copying the whole piece of code once and change it specifically for $my_array['notfruit'], then unset it from the array to use foreach loop to go through the remaining. i.e.

```
echo $my_array['notfruit']."is not fruit. Who put that in the array?";
unset ($my_array['notfruit']);
foreach ($my_array as $values) {
    echo $values." is fruit. I love fruit so I like ".$values;
}
```

It works but it sounds stupid, and can cause problem if the content in the foreach loop is long.

Comment: Where you get this array? Are you able to render array in order which you need?

Comment: I can, but I don't care the sequence of the remaining, so I feel that it is too much to order the whole array.

Comment: Your example of code conflicts with your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out any element with a key that doesn't begin with `fruit` pretty easily

```
$fruits = array_filter(
    $my_array,
    function ($key) {
        return fnmatch('fruit*', $key);
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
var_dump($fruits);
```

though using [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with the keys like this does require PHP >= 5.6

**EDIT**

For earlier versions of PHP, you can [swap the keys/values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) before filtering; then flip them again afterwards

```
$fruits = array_flip(
    array_filter(
        array_flip($my_array),
        function ($value) {
            return fnmatch('fruit*', $value);
        }
    )
);
var_dump($fruits);
```

Comment: I love the new flags in 5.6! So useful, nice example here :D

Comment: Very useful, and I'm glad that I keep our servers up-to-date, giving access to more and more powerful and useful features with every new release of PHP

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

You can, however pull whatever functionality you intended to have in the `foreach` into a funcion, then call the funcion specifically for the `notfruit` value, then run the foreach.

```
function foo($val) {
    // do stuff with $val
}

$my_array = array(
    "fruit1" => "apple",
    "fruit2" => "orange",
    "notfruit" => "hamburger",
    "fruit3" => "banana"
)

foo($my_array['nofriut']);
unset($my_array['nofruit']);

foreach($my_array as $val) {
    foo($val);
}
```

#### EDIT

Or if your case is as simple as your updated question, simply check if the key is `nofruit`

```
foreach($my_array as $key => $val) {
    if($key === "nofruit") {
        echo "$val is not fruit. Who put that in the array?";
    } else {
        echo "$val is fruit. I love fruit so I like $val";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the real case is also some display, but much longer than this one. The content under the key is also an object instead of a simple string.

Comment: So my solution above the edit should fit quite well for your case, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    <?php
    $my_array = array(
        "fruit1" => "apple",
        "fruit2" => "orange",
        "notfruit" => "hamburger",
        "fruit3" => "banana"
    );
   $new_value['notfruit'] = $my_array['notfruit'];
  unset($my_array['notfruit']);
  $newarray=array_merge($new_value,$my_array);
  print_r($newarray);
    ?>
```

Result:`Array ( [notfruit] => hamburger [fruit1] => apple [fruit2] => orange [fruit3] => banana )`

Comment: my thoughts exactly :)

Comment: This will add hamburger with a numerical key (0) instead of 'notfruit'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$no_fruit = $my_array['nofruit']; // grab the value
unset($my_array['nofruit']); // remove value from array
array_unshift($my_array, $no_fruit); // add value at the beginning
```

or

```
$no_fruit = $my_array['nofruit']; // grab the value
unset($my_array['nofruit']); // remove value from array
$my_array = array('nofruit' => $no_fruit ) + $my_array; // add value at the beginning
```

Comment: This will add hamburger with a numerical key (0) instead of 'notfruit'.

Comment: I have tried this one, but it fails, due to exactly the reason mentioned by rjdown.

Comment: That doesn't really matter because you already KNOW it is nofruit. It is the first one for your foreach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addition in arrays, which is more performant than array_unshift.

So unset it, and then add it back:

```
unset($my_array['notfruit']);
$my_array = array('notfruit' => 'hamburger') + $my_array;
var_dump($my_array);
```

Or if you want to use a variable:

```
$keyToMove = 'notfruit';
$val = $my_array[$keyToMove];
unset($my_array[$keyToMove]);
$newArray = array($keyToMove => $val) + $my_array;
var_dump($newArray);
```

Obviously you can put this all in a loop, applying it to any that you need to move.

Answer (score 0):

There is too many options.

1 . Using array_merge or array_replace (i think that it is the simplest way)

```
$my_array = array_merge(['notfruit' => null], $my_array);
// $my_array = array_replace(['notfruit' => null], $my_array);

foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
}
```

2 . Using generators.

```
$my_array = array(
    "fruit1" => "apple",
    "fruit2" => "orange",
    "notfruit" => "hamburger",
    "fruit3" => "banana"
);

$generator = function($my_array){
    yield 'notfruit'=>$my_array['notfruit'];
    unset($my_array['notfruit']);
    foreach($my_array as $key => $value)
        yield $key => $value;
};

foreach ($generator($my_array) as $key=>$value){
    var_dump($key, $value);
}
```

3 . Readding value

```
$no_fruit = $my_array['nofruit']; 
unset($my_array['nofruit']); 
$my_array['nofruit'] = $no_fruit;
$my_array = array_reverse($my_array, true);

foreach ($my_array as $key=>$value){
    var_dump($key, $value);
}
```

4 . Using infinitive iterator

```
$infinate = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($my_array));
$limit_iterator = new LimitIterator(
    $infinate, 
    array_search('notfruit', array_keys($my_array)), // position of desired key
    count($my_array));

foreach ($limit_iterator as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
}
```